# QT special comments //: //[num] etc

Tags: c++, qt, comments

What means this special comments in qt examples folder?

I know about "//:" this is a comment than would be taken to a translation program if the next line contains tr("").

The code between //[] seems to be taken to the generated html documentation.

Is there a document with full description of special comments?

Comment: I've seen comments like `// [10]` in almost all sources from qt _/examples_ folder. I think `10` is a tag. And also think this comments parsed by help-creation parser to cut tag-related content and paste it in docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt uses [Doxygen Special Commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) in it's code comments.  [Okay, to be correct, Doxygen extends Qt's comment special commands.]  The special commands are used to control the generation of the documentation when it is run on the code.  The Trolls who maintain Qt have their own tool they use to generate documents from the code.  [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) was written to give us mere mortals a tool we could use.

One of the things you can do with Doxygen (and I assume Qt's tool) is include example code in the documentation.  Often, only part of the code is needed, so there are some special commands that can be used to control what portion of the file is displayed (*e.g.* [`\line`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdline)).  They rely on finding markers in the code.  IMHO, the `// [xx]` are simply those markers.

Answer (score 1):

[This is the document for translation comments](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/i18n-source-translation.html), no mention of `//[num]` though....